# How to disable suggestion while typing in powershell

Tags: powershell, intellisense, interactive, psreadline, powershell-7

While executing commands in `PowerShell` it's automatically suggesting texts

[image]

How can I *disable* these *suggestions* and also in future if I want to enable the *suggestions* how can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`Set-PSReadLineOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption) cmdlet:

To *disable* all suggestions:

```bash
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource None
```

*Enabling* offers several options, depending on what *source(s)* should be used for completions: `History`, `Plugin`, or `HistoryAndPlugin` (the default).

See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/announcing-psreadline-2-1-with-predictive-intellisense/) for details.

---

Note:

- Perhaps surprisingly, the cmdlets that configure the behavior of the [`PSReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline) module, such as `Set-PSReadLineOption`, do *not*  do so *persistently* - they only affect the session at hand.
- Therefore, in order to make (what are effectively) *persistent* configuration changes, place the command above in your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file.

  - Note: Said file does *not* exist by default; to create it (and its parent directory) on demand, use the following command:

    ```bash
    if (-not (Test-Path $PROFILE)) { $null = New-Item -Force $PROFILE }
    ```
  - Once you've ensured its existence, to open it for editing it in your system's default text editor, so you can add the desired command(s), call:

    ```bash
    Invoke-Item $PROFILE
    ```
  - Changes to your `$PROFILE` file take effect in *future* sessions (except in those sessions explicitly started *without* profiles, using the [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s `-NoProfile` switch).